# Where can I get permission string to use with user_access?

Tags: users

There is a long permission list at `admin/people/permissions`.
For example there is permission with title `Article: Edit any content`.
But where can I get the string which can be used with function `user_access()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty lo-tech but you can actually get it with developer tools/firebug.

If you inspect one of the checkboxes next to a permission you'll see something like this for the `name` attribute:

[image]

That's your permission string: **edit any media_gallery content**

The more bulletproof way to find out the exact string would be to inspect the module's implementation of `hook_permission()`. In this case that would be [`node_permission()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_permission/7) which internally calls [`node_list_permissions()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_list_permissions/7).

If you look through that last function it should become quite clear what permission strings are generated for the various node operations.

Answer (score 3):

Pop Devel on your site and head to *yoursite.com/devel/php* and enter the following:

```
$permissions = module_invoke('node', 'permission');
dsm($permissions);
```

The key for each part of the array will be the string you want to apply the permission.

The following will get a list of permissions on every enabled module on your site (modules sorted by name):

```
foreach (module_list(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE) as $module) {
  if ($permissions = module_invoke($module, 'permission')) {
    // Print the module title
    dsm($module);
    // Print the permisions
    dsm($permissions);
  }
}
```